# If Interface/AbstractClass already commented what do I have to write to subclass?

Tags: c#, .net, comments

If the methods in an Interface or AbstractClass are already commented (thats how its correct right? Always comment the interface and abtract methods), what do I have to write into the Subclass methods? Nothing? Or maybe a reference(how?)? What is the correct way? And what do I do, if lets say I commented a Method in a Subclass, but I would like to extend it in the Subclass method?

Comment: You don't ever *have* to comment a method at all.  You should be using comments to add information to other developers that they can't see from the code itself.  If everything that's important for them to know is obvious from the code then adding redundant comments without useful information is more harmful than helpful.

Comment: I dont waste my time commenting none of these things. I think everything (every single name) should be semantically meaningful, and there's nothing to comment in ReadById(int id) signature. I just comment things that needs to be commented, and most of these things are spaguethi code inside methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If saying "commented" you mean add a `comment`, so `VisualStudio` intellisence would show you it: There is no concept of comment derivation(polymorphism), so for every child of that `interface` or `abstract class` you have to add a new comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to say that you should comment both.  My main reasonings for this is that intellisense will not pick up the base method's comments if the override does not, also the override may have different logic which means the original comment may not be accurate.